# svg path css animation paused, jquery running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, path

i'm trying to use a svg animated by css. my first problem was that it autotriggers, so after searching a little bit i found out i could declare it as paused, and then trigger it from jQuery using `$("path").css("animation-play-state", "running");`

my problem now, is that yes, it triggers when it's supposed to, but it's like it starts the animation and after milliseconds, it stops for like 1second, and the resumes fluidly until the end.

does anybody know what might be causing this behaviour? the animation is kinda useless as it is...

HTML

```
<div class="page_wrapper_home">
        <div id="logo_home">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                viewBox="0 0 1183.1 223" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1183.1 223;" xml:space="preserve">
                <style type="text/css">
                    .st0 {
                        fill: #2A4054;
                        stroke: #2A4054;
                        stroke-width: 3;
                        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                    }
                </style>
                <g>
                    <path class="st0" d="M54.2,212.8c-6.8-1.2-12.9-3.4-18.4-6.7c-5.5-3.3-10.5-7.3-15-12.1c-5.1-5.9-8.6-12.3-10.7-19.4
        c-2.1-7.1-3-14.4-2.7-22c0.3-4.8,1.3-9.6,3.2-14.4c1.9-4.8,4.1-9.1,6.8-13c5.5-7.5,11.8-13.1,19-16.8c7.2-3.7,14.6-5.9,22.3-6.4
        c7.7-0.5,15.2,0.5,22.5,3c7.3,2.5,13.9,6.3,19.6,11.4c5.7,5.1,10.3,11.3,13.6,18.7c3.3,7.4,4.8,15.7,4.4,24.9H66.2v-5.6h47.6v-0.8
        c-2.3-18-11.1-31.6-26.6-40.8c-4.7-2.8-9.7-4.6-15.1-5.4c-5.4-0.8-10.8-0.9-16.1-0.2c-6,0.7-11.7,2.5-17,5.5
        c-5.3,3-9.9,6.7-13.8,11.1c-5.6,6.3-9.3,13.2-11.2,20.7c-1.9,7.5-2.1,14.9-0.7,22.2c1.4,7.3,4.4,14.1,9,20.4
        c4.6,6.3,10.5,11.5,17.7,15.5c3.5,1.9,7.2,3.2,11.2,4c4,0.8,7.9,1.5,11.8,2v4.6c-1.7,0-3.2,0-4.5,0
        C57.2,213.2,55.8,213.1,54.2,212.8z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M136.8,106.8l53.6,100.4L240,106.8h5.4v0.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.7-0.4,1.2c-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.4,1.2l-51,103.6H188
        l-57.2-106.4H136.8z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M264.5,211.4l-0.6,1.8h-6.6l1.8-4.2l87-198c0.9-2.1,4.5-2.1,5.4,0l87,198l1.8,4.2h-6.6l-0.6-1.8L348.8,19.7
        L264.5,211.4z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M585.5,211.4l-0.6,1.8h-6.6l1.8-4.2l87-198c0.9-2.1,4.5-2.1,5.4,0l87,198l1.8,4.2h-6.6l-0.6-1.8L669.8,19.7
        L585.5,211.4z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M825,215c-9.7-1.6-18-5-24.8-10.3c-6.8-5.3-12.6-12.1-17.4-20.5v29h-5.6v-167h5.6v88.4
        c2.5-4.3,5.4-8.3,8.5-12.1c3.1-3.8,6.8-7.1,11.1-9.9c5.7-3.6,12.2-6.2,19.4-7.9c7.2-1.7,14.2-1.8,21-0.3c8.9,1.7,16.6,5,23.1,9.9
        c6.5,4.9,11.6,10.6,15.4,17.2c3.8,6.6,6.2,13.7,7.2,21.3c1,7.6,0.5,15-1.4,22.3c-1.9,7.3-5.4,14-10.5,20.2
        c-5.1,6.2-11.7,11.2-20,15.1c-4.8,2.3-10,3.8-15.5,4.7C835.5,216,830.2,215.9,825,215z M823.6,209.4c0.3,0,0.8,0.1,1.6,0.2
        c0.8,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.6,0.2h12.8c4.3-0.1,8.5-1.1,12.8-3c4.3-1.9,8.2-4.3,11.9-7.3c3.7-3,6.9-6.4,9.8-10.2c2.9-3.8,5-7.6,6.3-11.5
        c0.7-2.1,1.4-4.3,2.1-6.6c0.7-2.3,1.1-4.5,1.1-6.8c0.4-10.4-1.4-19.5-5.3-27.2c-3.9-7.7-9.1-13.9-15.4-18.6
        c-6.3-4.7-13.4-7.7-21.3-9.1c-7.9-1.4-15.6-1-23.1,1.1c-7.5,2.1-14.4,6.1-20.6,12c-6.2,5.9-10.8,13.7-13.9,23.6
        c-1.2,3.6-1.8,7.5-1.9,11.6c-0.1,4.1,0.3,8.2,1.2,12.3c0.9,4.1,2.2,8,4,11.7c1.8,3.7,4,7,6.5,9.8c4.1,4.7,8.6,8.4,13.3,11.3
        C811.8,205.8,817.3,207.9,823.6,209.4z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M952.6,215c-5.5-0.8-10.7-2.3-15.6-4.6c-4.9-2.3-9.4-5.1-13.5-8.5c-4.1-3.4-7.6-7.4-10.6-11.9
        c-3-4.5-5.2-9.5-6.7-15c0-0.3-0.2-1.2-0.5-2.7c-0.3-1.5-0.6-2.6-0.9-3.3c0-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.6c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.8
        c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.2-1.2v-58.8h5v56.8c0,2.3,0.5,4.9,1.4,7.8c0.9,2.9,1.9,5.5,2.8,7.8c3.1,6.7,7.4,12.4,12.9,17.1
        c5.5,4.7,11.6,8.2,18.3,10.4c6.7,2.2,13.6,3,20.8,2.4s14-2.9,20.4-6.9c2.9-1.9,5.8-4.2,8.7-6.9c2.9-2.7,5.5-5.8,7.8-9.1
        c2.3-3.3,4.2-6.8,5.7-10.4c1.5-3.6,2.2-7.2,2.2-10.8l0.8-59.2h4.6v106.6h-5v-29c-3.2,5.3-6.9,10.1-11,14.3
        c-4.1,4.2-8.6,7.7-13.5,10.4c-4.9,2.7-10.1,4.7-15.8,5.8C964.8,215.8,958.8,215.9,952.6,215z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M1041.4,47.2v14.6h-4.6V47.2H1041.4z M1041.4,107.2v106h-4.6v-106H1041.4z" />
                    <path class="st0" d="M1068,107.2v28.4l0.6-0.4c2.5-3.7,4.9-7.2,7.1-10.4c2.2-3.2,5.2-6.1,8.9-8.8c6.4-4.9,13.5-8.3,21.4-10
        c7.9-1.7,15.6-1.9,23.2-0.5c7.6,1.4,14.7,4.3,21.4,8.7c6.7,4.4,12,10.2,16,17.4c2.1,3.6,4,7.5,5.5,11.7c1.5,4.2,2.3,8.4,2.3,12.5
        v57.4h-4.6v-55c0-3.7-0.7-7.6-2-11.7c-1.3-4.1-2.9-7.7-4.8-10.9c-3.2-5.6-7.1-10.3-11.6-14.1c-4.5-3.8-9.5-6.7-14.9-8.7
        c-5.4-2-11-3.1-16.7-3.2c-5.7-0.1-11.3,0.7-16.7,2.4c-5.4,1.7-10.5,4.4-15.3,8c-4.8,3.6-8.9,8.2-12.4,13.8
        c-1.9,3.2-3.6,6.8-5.1,10.9c-1.5,4.1-2.3,8-2.3,11.7v56.8h-5v-106H1068z" />
                </g>
            </svg>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#logo_home
    position: absolute
    top: 30%
    left: 50%
    margin: 0
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    width: 50%

path
    stroke: #ffffff
    fill: #ffffff
    stroke-dasharray: 615
    opacity: 10
    //animation-play-state: paused
    animation: animate 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.23, 1, 0.1) paused


@keyframes animate
    0%
        opacity: 0
        fill: none
        stroke-dashoffset: 615
    30%
        opacity: 10
        fill: none
        stroke-dashoffset: 615
    90%
        fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
    100%
        opacity: 10
        fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
        stroke-dashoffset: 0
```

JAVASCRIPT / JQuery

```
$(function () {
    toggleSliders();
    setTimeout(() => {
        $("path").css("animation-play-state", "running");
    }, 3000);

........
```

Comment: opacity: 10? opacity's range is 0..1

Comment: yeah... i don't really know since i follwed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0Ic8QcvyK8 but the animation works well, it's only having problems when starting it paused and then running it from JQuery. i don't think opacity is the problem here. i think the problem might be in the use of animation play state and the paused and running states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it, the problem was the stroke-dashoffset, which wasn't in a nice value. turning it to 915 solved the problem. in the video I saw, they setted the value just changing the value by hand and judging by the eye. the right value can actually be retrieved using javascript. I did it this way:

```
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
        var total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            if(paths[i].getTotalLength() > total){
                total = paths[i].getTotalLength();
            }
        }
```

so this way i found the longest path, which was 915.1467895507812. a value of 915 worked just fine.

hope this helps somebody!